# Finding the methods/properties on a swf object

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I have a swf object embedded into a web page.  Without having access to the source code of the swf file, how can I find the methods/properties that are exposed?

For example...

```
alert(document.getElementById('swfObject').id);
```

...returns a pop-up of "swfObject".  And this...

```
document.getElementById('swfObject').someMethod();
```

...executes someMethod.

Thanks.